# Setting up a static IP from ISP

Tags: centos, webserver, webmin

I think my question might be an easy one but i struggle a little with setting up servers. I have a CentOS 6 setup. I have added Webmin and Virtualmin. I set this up with a static IP address and had virtual IPs setup. everything was working fine. Now i have changed ISP and have a static IP address. They asked me for the MAC address for the server and set it up. I changed the information in the server (ifcfg-eth0) to reflect what they gave me but i am unable to see the server (inside or outside using the IP address given). Also if i am accessing this locally there must be a better way to reach  than by the static IP. Going out and coming back in doesnt make sense to me. Do i need to do port forwarding or something? Thanks.
Further Update:
the only thing in between the outside and the server is the cable modem/router for the ISP. Supposedly they set that up. It is not something i can do from my end.

Comment: Please clarify "unable to see the server". Is this from the inside or the outside? Have you changed the IP address for the interface or only changed the configuration? (If unsure, restarting networking or (ugh) rebooting will apply any pending change.) Is there a router/firewall between your server and the Internet? Remember to [update your question with additional information](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/206536/edit) rather than losing it in the comments.

Comment: I have updated the  above.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `ifcfg-eth0` updates the saved configuration ready for the next time the interface is brought up. You need to restart networking or reboot your server to apply it to the interface.

For CentOS 6 I believe the correct command to restart networking is

```
service network restart    # Or /etc/init.d/network restart
```

Comment: That would be great but i always reboot after changes. So i am still at square 1.

Answer (score 0):

So it was easier than i thought. I needed to change the NAT Mode in the modem to be bridged and then everything works fine now.

Comment: Pleased you're sorted. Wasn't it bridged in your previous scenario too?